# JavaScript not working for button inside form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm trying to use JavaScript and PHP together for the first time.

PHP, as far as I know, requires the submit button to be inside the form tags. However, for some reason, JavaScript ONLY works if the submit button is outside the form. If I move the submit button inside the form tags I get this error: 
"index.html:94 Uncaught TypeError: submitBtn is not a function".

Is there a way to either 1) get PHP to work with the button OUTSIDE the form? OR 2) get JavaScript to work with the button INSIDE the form?

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="form" id="form">
        <label for="name">Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="name"><br>
                <label for="email">Email</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="email"><br>
                <label for="comment">Reason for contacting</label><br>
                <textarea rows="3" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
                <br>
    </div>      
    <button type="button" name="submitButton" id="submitBtn" onclick="submitBtn()">SEND</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function submitBtn() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var comment = document.getElementById('comment');
    if(name.value.length > 1 && name.value.length < 50) {
        if(email.length > 5 && email.length < 50 && email.indexOf('@') >= 0 && email.indexOf('.') >= 0 && !(email.indexOf(' ') >= 0)) {
            if(comment.value.length > 9 && comment.value.length < 500) {
        alert("Thanks");
            } else {
        alert("Message must be between 10 and 500 characters");
    }
        } else {
  alert("Not a valid email");
}
    } else {
alert("Name must be longer than three characters");
    }
};
```

Comment: `function submitBtn(){}` should be inside the `<script>` tag and above the `</body>`

Comment: There's an `<input type="email" />` btw. And you might instead want to use `<form onsubmit="">`

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `onsubmit` in the `form` tag?

Comment: Don't declare global functions with the same name as the id of an element.

Comment: Thanks it works now.

However if use <form onsubmit="submitBtn()"> as 4castle1 suggested it stops working. Can I just call the function on the button? Or will this cause an issue later as I add PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Change the button's id to **submitBtnId**

elements's ID and function's name cannot be same, because they are all identifiers.

```
<button type="button" name="submitButton" id="submitBtnId" onclick="submitBtn()">SEND</button>
```

Comment: The reason this works is because some browsers declare id's as globals, so they shadow any other global variables/functions that might have the same name. The best way to do this is to not use inline-JavaScript or globals at all, and assign the event handler in the JS instead.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the function name or the button id because both are same.